# use of __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, declspec

I am making my .dll library implemented in OOP manner

my macros are:

```
#ifndef _SWC_
#define DLLINTERFACE  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLINTERFACE __declspec(dllimport)
```

after I put `DLLINTERFACE` before a class name using some `std`s on it, compiler gives me several warnings that I should provide a `dll-interface` for each function that I use with  `std`s. I try to solve this by putting `DLLINTERFACE` on some function but gives me an error now because I already put it on the class name. Perhaps, I can remove the warning by defining all of my public functions with `DLLINTERFACE` with it. But how can I eliminate the warnings by defining only the class name, not the individual functions?

like this:

```
class DLLINTERFACE Foo
{
 public:
    std::string bar();
};
```

but not this:

```
class Foo
{
 public:
    std::string DLLINTERFACE bar();
};
```

Comment: Pretty unclear.  This kind of warning is displayed when a dllexported class has members that are not exported as well.  It is just a warning.  An exported function returning std::string is very risky, it will malfunction when client code doesn't use the **exact** same version of the CRT or does not share the same CRT.  Compiling with /MD is crucial.

Comment: Lack of googling makes me post this comment. Yeah, and they suggest that it is safer to use a .lib than .dll when using `stl`s.

Comment: short answer is : template class DLLINTERFACE std::string; before class definition.long answer is long :) try to avoid stl export and keep dll interface as much as possible close to C (not c++) i.e. use const char* not std::string.